# Is there a way to add actions to the clipboard dropdown?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have two methods / actions that I've added to the top ellipse containing 'Actions' - but I'm wondering if there's a way to add them to the clipboard dropdown (on a custom screen):

[image]

If not, it's not a big deal, but if there's a way it would be ideal.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the page actions under the graph Actions collection.

In this case you are looking for the "CopyPaste" action and the following code in the constructor or initialize method will add a button to this drop down:

```
var copyPasteAction = this.Actions["CopyPaste"];
copyPasteAction.AddMenuAction(testButton);
```

testButton in this case is another PXAction which is your button you want to add to CopyPaste.

result:

[image]